# Integral involving logarithm: $\int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln x}{(x+a)(x+b)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, improper-integrals

How to solve the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ \ln x}{(x+a)(x+b)} dx,$$
where $a,b>0$ and $a \neq b$. I was looking for some kind of substitution. However, I don't see an obvious one.

Thanks!

Comment: Is complex analysis fair game? One can evaluate the integral via the residue theorem.

Comment: What contour are you using? If you use the 'keyhole' contour it looks promising, but it turns out that the interesting part of the integral cancels so you don't get anything useful.

Comment: @user5713492 Standard keyhole contour. Integrate $\dfrac{(\log z)^2}{(z+a)(z+b)}$. The $(\log x)^2$ cancels, and you keep a $\log x$.

Comment: Cool. I wasn't looking for such a refinement.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you make the substitution $ \displaystyle u = \frac{ab}{x}$, the integral becomes $$-\int^{0}_{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(\frac{ab}{u} \right)}{(\frac{ab}{u}+a)(\frac{ab}{u}+b)} \frac{ab}{u^{2}} \, du = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(ab) - \ln(u)}{(u+a)(u+b)} \, du. $$

Therefore, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{(x+a)(x+b)} \, dx = \frac{\ln (ab)}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+a)(x+b)}.  $$

You can then use partial fractions to complete the evaluation.

Comment: Pretty fine and pretty clear.

Comment: i was given this Q, in the course of "complex functions" and was being asked to solve it using ***complex analysis***.  do you have any suggestion for this kind of problem?

Comment: if this integral is over the field  of complex numbers and an answer must include using  complex analysis. will the answer be different?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming $a<b$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{(x+a)(x+b)}\,dx &=& \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+a}-\frac{x}{x+b}\right)\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{2(b-a)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{b}{(x+b)^2}-\frac{a}{(x+a)^2}\right)\log^2(x)\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
by integration by parts. However, 
$$ I(a) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a \log^2(x)}{(x+a)^2}\,dx =2\zeta(2)+\log^2(a)$$
is straightforward to prove through the substitution $x=az$ and differentiation under the integral sign. It follows that:

> $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{(x+a)(x+b)}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\log^2(b)-\log^2(a)}{2(b-a)}}.$$

Comment: i was given this Q, in the course of "complex functions" and was being asked to solve it using complex analysis. do you have any suggestion for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 6):

One way to integrate the $\log$ function is as follows: by parts let $u = \log x$ and $dv = 1$. Then:

$\int u \frac{dv}{dx} = uv - \int v\frac{du}{dx} = x\log x - \int \frac{x}{x} = x\log x - x$

Knowing this and that your integral is a product of three separate integrals you can then repeatedly apply integration by parts twice to the remaining terms.

Comment: i was given this Q, in the course of "complex functions" and was being asked to solve it using complex analysis. do you have any suggestion for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3):

ter tests and substitutions, I calculated the integral by real methods.

Let $$\displaystyle{F(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln\,x}{(x+a)\,(x+b)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\,,0<a<b}$$ .

We $\displaystyle{x=\dfrac{1}{t}}$ set , so we have

$$\displaystyle{F(a,b)=-\int_{\infty}^{0}\dfrac{\ln(1/t)\,t^2}{(1+a\,t)\,(1+b\,t)}\,\dfrac{1}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{-\ln\,x}{(a\,x+1)\,(b\,x+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\,(I)}$$

On the other hand,

$$\displaystyle{\begin{aligned}F(a,b)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln\,(a\,b)+\ln\,(x/(a\,b))}{a\,b\,\left(x/a+1\right)\,\left(x/b+1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&\stackrel{y=x/a\,b}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln\,(a\,b)+\ln\,x}{(a\,x+1)\,(b\,x+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\,(II) \end{aligned}}$$

From relationships $\displaystyle{(I)\,,(II)}$ we get,

$$\displaystyle{\begin{aligned}2\,F(a,b)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln\,(a\,b)}{(a\,x+1)\,(b\,x+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\ln\,(a\,b)\,\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{b}{b-a}\,\dfrac{1}{b\,x+1}-\dfrac{a}{b-a}\,\dfrac{1}{a\,x+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\left[\dfrac{\ln\,(a\,b)}{b-a}\,\ln\,\left(\dfrac{b\,x+1}{a\,x+1}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}\\&=\dfrac{1}{b-a}\,\ln\,(a\,b)\,\ln\,(b/a) \end{aligned}}$$

That $$F(a,b)=\dfrac{1}{2\,(b-a)}\,\left(\ln^2\,b-\ln^2\,a\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using complex analysis:

We consider the complex function $f(z)=\frac{{\rm{Log}}^2{z}}{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}\,,\quad z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x+0i\;|\;x\leqslant0\}$, which is meromorphic at $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x+0i\;|\;x\leqslant0\}$ with simple poles $z=\alpha$, $z=\beta$ and the simple, closed curve $\gamma$, which is the summand of the anticlockwise oriented arc $C_r:=\big\{r\,{\rm{e}}^{it}\in{\mathbb{C}}\;\big|\; t\in(-\pi+\varepsilon,\pi-\varepsilon]\big\}\,, \; r\to+\infty\,,\;\varepsilon\to0^+\,, $ of the segment $\ell:=\big\{(r+\delta-t)\,{\rm{e}}^{i\pi}\in{\mathbb{C}}\;\big|\; t\in(\delta,r)\big\}$, of the clockwise oriented arc $C_\delta:=\big\{\delta\,{\rm{e}}^{-it}\in{\mathbb{C}}\;\big|\; t\in(-\pi+\varepsilon,\pi-\varepsilon]\big\}\,, \;\delta\to0^{+}\,,\;\varepsilon\to0^+\,,$ and of the segment $-\ell:=\big\{t\,{\rm{e}}^{-i\pi}\in{\mathbb{C}}\;\big|\; t\in(\delta,r)\big\}$.

[image]

We have that \begin{align*}
{\rm{Res}\,}\big(f(z), z=\alpha\big)&=\frac{1}{0!}\,\mathop{\lim}\limits_{z\to\alpha}\bigg(( z-\alpha)\,\dfrac{{\rm{Log}\,}^2{z}}{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}\bigg)\\
&=\mathop{\lim}\limits_{z\to\alpha}\dfrac{{\rm{Log}\,}^2{z}}{z-\beta}\\
&= \dfrac{\log^2{\alpha}}{\alpha-\beta}\,,\\
{\rm{Res}\,}\big(f(z), z=\beta\big)&=\frac{1}{0!}\,\mathop{\lim}\limits_{z\to\beta}\bigg(( z-\beta)\,\dfrac{{\rm{Log}\,}^2{z}}{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}\bigg)\\
&=\mathop{\lim}\limits_{z\to\beta}\dfrac{{\rm{Log}\,}^2{z}}{z-\alpha}\\
&=\dfrac{\log^2{\beta}}{\beta-\alpha}
\end{align*} and \begin{align*}
\displaystyle\oint_{\gamma}{f(z)\,dz}&=2\pi i\;\cancelto{1}{{\rm{I}\,}\big(\gamma, z=\alpha\big)}\,{\rm{Res}\,}\big(f(z), z=\alpha\big)+2\pi i\;\cancelto{1}{{\rm{I}\,}\big(\gamma, z=\beta\big)}\,{\rm{Res}\,}\big(f(z), z=\beta\big)\\
&=2\pi i\,\dfrac{\log^2{\alpha}}{\alpha-\beta}+2\pi i\,\dfrac{\log^2{\beta}}{\beta-\alpha}\\
&=2\pi i\,\dfrac{\log^2\beta-\log^2\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}&\Longrightarrow\\
\oint_{C_{r}}{f(z)\,dz}&+\oint_{\ell}{f(z)\,dz}+\oint_{C_{\delta}}{f(z)\,dz}+\oint_{-\ell}{f(z)\,dz}=2\pi i\,\dfrac{\log^2\beta-\log^2\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}\qquad(1)\,.
\end{align*}
Also \begin{align*}
\displaystyle\oint_{\ell}{f(z)\,dz}&=\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{{\rm{Log}\,}^2\big((r+\delta-t)\,{\rm{e}}^{i\pi}\big)\,\big((r+\delta-t)\,{\rm{e}}^{i\pi}\big)'}{\big((r+\delta-t)\,{\rm{e}}^{i\pi}-\alpha\big)\big((r+\delta-t)\,{\rm{e}}^{i\pi}-\beta\big)}\,dt}\\
&=\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\big(\log|-r-\delta+t|+i\,\pi\big)^2}{(-r-\delta+t-\alpha)(-r-\delta+t-\beta)}\,dt}\\
&\mathop{=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=}\limits^{\begin{subarray}{c}
 {s\,=\,r+\delta-t}\\
 {ds\,=\,-dt}\\
 \end{subarray}}\,\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\big(\log{s}+i\,\pi\big)^2}{(-s-\alpha)(-s-\beta)}\,ds}\\
&=\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\big(\log{t}+i\,\pi\big)^2}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}\,,\\
\displaystyle\oint_{-\ell}{f(z)\,dz}&=\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{{\rm{Log}\,}^2\big(t\,{\rm{e}}^{-i\pi}\big)\,\big(t\,{\rm{e}}^{-i\pi}\big)'}{\big(t\,{\rm{e}}^{-i\pi}-\alpha\big)\big(t\,{\rm{e}}^{-i\pi}-\beta\big)}\,dt}\\
&=-\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\big(\log|{-t}|-i\,\pi\big)^2}{(-t-\alpha)(-t-\beta)}\,dt}\\
&=-\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\big(\log{t}-i\,\pi\big)^2}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}\hspace{3.0cm}\Rightarrow\\
\int_{\ell}{f(z)\,dz}+\int_{-\ell}{f(z)\,dz}&=\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\big(\log{t}+i\,\pi\big)^2}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}-\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\big(\log{t}-i\,\pi\big)^2}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}\\
&=\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{4\pi\,i\,\log{t}}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}\,.
\end{align*}
By Estimation lemma we have that
$$\displaystyle\mathop{\lim}\limits_{r\to+\infty}\oint_{C_{r}}{f(z)\,dz}=\mathop{\lim}\limits_{\delta\to0^{+}}\oint_{C_{\delta}}{f(z)\,dz}=0\,.$$
So equation $(1)$ becames \begin{align*}
\mathop{\lim}\limits_{\begin{subarray}{c}
 {r\to+\infty}\\
 {\delta\to0^+}
 \end{subarray}}\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{4\pi\,i\,\log{t}}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}+\cancelto{0}{\mathop{\lim}\limits_{\begin{subarray}{c}
  {r\to+\infty}\\
  {\delta\to0^+}
  \end{subarray}}\int_{C_{r}}{f(z)\,dz}}+\cancelto{0}{\mathop{\lim}\limits_{\begin{subarray}{c}
  {r\to+\infty}\\
  {\delta\to0^+}
  \end{subarray}}\int_{C_{\delta}}{f(z)\,dz}}&=2\pi i\,\dfrac{\log^2\beta-\log^2\alpha}{\beta-\alpha} &\Rightarrow\\
\mathop{\lim}\limits_{\begin{subarray}{c}
 {r\to+\infty}\\
 {\delta\to0^+}
 \end{subarray}}\int_{\delta}^{r}{\dfrac{\log{t}}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}&=\dfrac{\log^2\beta-\log^2\alpha}{2\,(\beta-\alpha)} &\Rightarrow\\
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{\log{t}}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}\,dt}=\dfrac{\log^2\beta-\log^2\alpha}{2\,(\beta-\alpha)}\,.
\end{align*}

Comment: It seems Mathjax does not recognize `\cancelto`